# Read a KMS encrypted file from S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

How can I use boto3 resource to read a KMS encrypted file from S3 bucket?

Below is the snippet that I am using to read a non-encrypted file -

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
obj = s3.Object(bucket_name, key)
body = obj.get()['Body'].read()
print(' body = {}'.format(body))
```

Comment: What happens when you add KMS permissions (for the relevant KMS key) to your credentials and re-run this code against a KMS-encrypted object?

Comment: I am running this within a lambda function , can you please let me know how I can do that ?

Comment: Configure the Lambda function’s IAM role’s policy to include kms:* (temporarily) and then test with KMS-encrypted object.

Comment: Thanks @jarmod. This helped as well - https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1789. I was looking for a way to pass KMS key to read the data. However it looks like it is not needed

Comment: Right - you don't need to provide any KMS info on a GetObject request (which is what the boto3 resource-level methods are doing under the covers), unless you're doing CMK. You just need to have permission to access the KMS key for decryption. Glad you were able to get it working. I can write this up as an answer if that helps.

Comment: @jarmod , sure please do. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a helpful answer at [Do I need to specify the AWS KMS key when I download a KMS-encrypted object from Amazon S3?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/decrypt-kms-encrypted-objects-s3/)

> No, you don’t need to specify the AWS KMS key ID when you download an
>   SSE-KMS-encrypted object from an S3 bucket. Instead, you need the
>   permission to decrypt the AWS KMS key.

So, you don't need to provide KMS info on a GetObject request (which is what the boto3 resource-level methods are doing under the covers), unless you're doing [CMK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/concepts.html#master_keys). You just need to have permission to access the KMS key for decryption. S3/KMS will do the rest for you.

You can configure the IAM policy associated with the Lambda function’s IAM role per the linked article.